# UIButton: why is my UIControlStateSelected image offset?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uicontrol

I have a custom tab bar and controller taken from this [iDev Recipes article](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/#comment-525).   I have 2 issues:

1. My UIControlStateSelected image is too high vertically.
2. The text of the button drops to the bottom right corner on the selected item.

I've set a green layer border to denote the button borders:

[image]

I've determined that the offset is due to the code I'm using below to center the text and image on the button.  Why is this causing issues #1 and #2 above?

```
-(void) centerButtonImageAndText: (UIButton*) button {
    NSLog(@"CustomTabBar centerButtonImageAndText");
    // the space between the image and text
    CGFloat spacing = 0.0;
    // mark: this offsets the verticalOffset above for placing the button due to the          controller's selectedItemBackgroundImage: method
    CGFloat textAndImageOffset = TEXT_AND_IMAGE_OFFSET;

    // get the size of the elements here for readability
    CGSize imageSize = button.imageView.frame.size;
    CGSize titleSize = button.titleLabel.frame.size;

    // lower the text and push it left to center it
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
                                          0.0 + textAndImageOffset, - imageSize.width, -     (imageSize.height + spacing), 0.0);

    // the text width might have changed (in case it was shortened before due to 
    // lack of space and isn't anymore now), so we get the frame size again
    titleSize = button.titleLabel.frame.size;

    // raise the image and push it right to center it
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
                                          - (titleSize.height + spacing) +       textAndImageOffset, 0.0, 0.0, - titleSize.width);      
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to recreate this issue, but do not know what `TEXT_AND_IMAGE_OFFSET` should be set to.